# Mount XFS partition on OS X using OSXFUSE

Tags: macos, filesystems, xfs

How can I mount an XFS-partition on OS X 10.7 using [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.com/)?

In their [filesystem repository](https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems) under `filesystems-c/unixfs` I have found `minixfs`. However, I'm not sure how to go about installing it and using it to mount the partition, hence I would be grateful if someone could write a short guide/tutorial. I wasn't able to find any instructions on the topic elsewhere.

Comment: It's not *"Mini XFS"*, it's [Minix FS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX).

Comment: Did you Google for `osxfuse xfs` and find [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fusexfs/) on the first page? If so, why doesn't it work for you? If not, *why not?*

Comment: @DanielBeck D'oh! I don't know _how_ I missed it. Bonus question - is there a way of getting around the write-only mode of `fuse-xfs`?

Comment: @DanielBeck *read-only. What is up with me today...

Comment: [Write operations are not implemented](http://sourceforge.net/p/fusexfs/trunk/ci/dea73332be091793f4e9212bfcadf276e7080ea2/tree/src/fuse/fuse_xfs.c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel Beck pointed out, there is [Fuse-XFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fusexfs/), which let's you mount XFS under OS X in read-only mode.

From author's [website](http://www.ahardy.za.net/Home/fusexfs):

> Fuse-xfs is a MacFuse (OSXFUSE) driver for XFS filesystems. This driver allows Mac OS 10.7 with OSXFUSE/MacFuse to mount XFS filesystems in read only mode.
>
> The journal is ignored, but basic read only operations should work fine.
>
> This software should be considered alpha, and provides no guarantees that the XFS filesystem remains unaltered (although the code does not support writing in any way). Use of the software is entirely at the users own risk.

Comment: Still works like a charm under macOS Catalina Beta (10.15)!

Answer (score 2):

1. Install FUSE for OSX
2. Connect the HD partitioned with XFS
3. Run Disk Utility, you should be able to see the mounted device (e.g: disk3)
4. `ls /dev/disk3*`, you should be able to see the partition (e.g: disk3s1)
5. create the mount point (e.g: `/mnt/my_xfs_hd`)
6. `sudo fuse-xfs /dev/disk3s1 -- /mnt/my_xfs_hd -o default_permissions,allow_other`
7. `cd /mnt/my_xfs_hd`, you should now have read-only access to all the data stored in the XFS partition

Answer (score 1):

minixfs is a file system for the minix operating system (MINIX-FS), rather than a small implentation for XFS (mini-xfs) :-)

So, look out for FUSE-XFS.